# Are there any issues using Arrow Key Stepper to scroll when the rows have tabIndex or contentEditable enabled?

Tags: contenteditable, keyboard-events, vertical-scrolling, tabindex, react-virtualized

We've implemented React-Vitualized using single column Grid with rows that are enabled for keyboard event (onKeyUp/onKeyDown/onKeyPress). We are using Arrow-Key-Stepper to enable ArrowUp/ArrowDown scrolling of the rows.

All works quite well even with PgUp/PgDn, Home/End, Space and Shift-Space. However, when we add either tabIndex and/or contenteditable attributes to the rows (required for keyboard events), scrolling freezes when the focused rows scrolls out-of-view and removed from the DOM. We can regain control by using Tab key and/or the mouse.

QUESTION: Why is tabIndex/contenteditable attributes causing scrolling failure?

I am not allowed to reproduce the code publicly. Not asking for solution nor code but more an opinion from a more experienced source. This is the last issue for our implementation of this widget library, which has been very good thus far.

Appreciate any suggest/opinion.

Comment: You don't have to reproduce the code, just sample code with the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, when we add either tabIndex and/or contenteditable attributes to the rows (required for keyboard events), scrolling freezes when the focused rows scrolls out-of-view and removed from the DOM.

I'm curious why the rows themselves need this attribute? The outer container rendered by `ArrowKeyStepper` has a tab-index, in order to be focusable. This is how `ArrowKeyStepper` listens to keyboard events.

If the row is focused, then when it goes out of the viewport, `ArrowKeyStepper` is left listening to ... nothing. The way to fix this is to use a class component to render your cell and conditionally self-focusing:

```
class Cell extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => this._maybeFocus();
  componentDidUpdate = () => this._maybeFocus();

  render() {
    const {
      columnIndex,
      rowIndex,
      scrollToColumn,
      scrollToRow,
      style,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div
        style={style}
        ref={this._setRef}
        tabIndex={1}
      >
        {/* Your content here... */}
      </div>
    );
  };

  _maybeFocus = () => {
    const {
      columnIndex,
      rowIndex,
      scrollToColumn,
      scrollToRow,
    } = this.props;

    if (
      columnIndex === scrollToColumn &&
      rowIndex === scrollToRow
    ) {
      this._ref.focus();
    }
  }

  _setRef = ref => {
    this._ref = ref;
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Our use case requires the ability for users to select a row/multiple rows (using Tab/Arrows/Mouse/Tap) and when hitting 'Enter' triggers submit of the selected content. We also do use standard submit button outside the list, but keyboard only functionality is really important for the client.